# How to install localstack on windows 10

Tags: python, localstack

I try to install localstack on windows with command

`pip install localstack`

This command works few seconds and ends with error:

```
 Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\tabulate.exe
```

The `C:\Python310\Scripts\` folder contains `pip.exe`, `pip3.exe` and `pip3.10.exe` files.

- How to add `tabulate` (package(?)) to the this folder?

---

PS that is interesting - each time after `pip install localstack` command execution I received different required files, in the first time it was `cmark.exe`, then `tabulate.exe`, and now pysemver.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `pip install --user localstack`, this error can occur if you do not have the permission to install packages globally.